# SILK Framework: Restrict-to SPARQL query

Tags: xml, sparql, rdf, linked-data

I'm trying to test SILK framework on two simple rdf files. I imported the two files correctly, and created a LinkSpec to generate a simple sameAs link. Prefixes are all correct, however, no link is generated.

Below are the parts of the files that are similar and should be linked:

1.

```
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/8286635/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/8286635/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Champ de Mars Tour Eiffel Railway Station</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/6254976/"/>
</gn:Feature>
```

2.

```
<gn:Feature rdf:about="http://sws.geonames.org/8286635/">
<rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/8286635/about.rdf"/>
<gn:name>Champ de Mars Tour Eiffel Railway Station</gn:name>
<gn:neighbour rdf:resource="http://sws.geonames.org/6254976/"/>
</gn:Feature>
```

Below is the LinkSpec file where the problem is supposed to be:

```xml
<Interlinks>
 <Interlink id="link3">
  <SourceDataset dataSource="nearby" var="a" typeUri="RDF/XML">
   <RestrictTo>?c <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#name> ?a .</RestrictTo>
  </SourceDataset>
  <TargetDataset dataSource="neighbour" var="b" typeUri="RDF/XML">
   <RestrictTo>?d <http://www.geonames.org/ontology#name> ?b .</RestrictTo>
  </TargetDataset>
  <LinkageRule linkType="owl:sameAs">
   <Compare id="equality1" required="true" weight="1" metric="equality" threshold="0.0" indexing="true">
    <Input id="sourcePath1" path="/gn:name"/>
    <Input id="targetPath1" path="/gn:name"/>
   </Compare>
   <Filter/>
  </LinkageRule>
  <Outputs>
   <Output id="output"/>
  </Outputs>
 </Interlink>
</Interlinks>
```

The link is supposed to catch up the similar features based on their names' similarity . Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Shouldn't you declare some output file?

Comment: First, try to replace `<http://www.geonames.org/ontology#name>` with [`gn:name`](https://app.assembla.com/wiki/show/silk/Link_Specification_Language).

Comment: And does it work with `<Input path="?c/gn:name" />` and `<Input path="?d/gn:name" />` ?

Comment: this is a snap of the code. it has output declared and the file is generated but is empty.

Comment: the URI of geonames is entered using the graphical interface as gn:name and the gn prefix is defined, but when exporting the link specifications it shows it with URIs.

Comment: regarding `?c/gn:name` , the i entered them this way in the GUI and the code converted it so too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the prefix of Geonames:

It was

```
<Prefix id="gn" namespace="http://www.geonames.org/ontology#"/>
```

instead of

```
<Prefix id="gn" namespace="http://www.geonames.org/ontology#/"/>
```

Comment: By the way, it's still wrong in your answer since both lines are exactly the same...

Comment: Thanks, apparently i'm new here